# Cent os 7 bash command not found

Tags: node.js, bash

I tried to install node from this example (logged as root):

```
yum install -y gcc-c++ make

curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | -E bash -

yum install nodejs
```

But I keep getting error bash command not found...

How do I add bash command?

I tried searching for it but I get only `bash_completion` that I installed as well but it doesn't work anyway....

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The command you shared looks incomplete. Try something like this

```
[root@server ~]# curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash
```

or if you still need the -E flag, add that **after** the bash command, like so:

```
[root@server ~]# curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -E
```

Your original command was passing the output of the curl command to the '-E' "command", followed by the bash command, and I'm guessing that's why you got an error; similar to this one:

```
[root@server ~]# curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | -E bash -
-bash: -E: command not found
```

It's stating that the -E command is not found.

These 'flags' as they are called, are parameters that are passed to commands to change the behaviour of the application/command.